# Make sure that the browser displays everything at once

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have this website that is heavy in images and text and on slow connections, internet browsers or computers with low RAM the text is loaded first then the images take a while to load. How can I make sure that everything is displayed out at the same time?

Solutions I've thought of:

1. Output Buffering -  `ob_start` and `ob_end_flush` at the top and bottom of my PHP script   to make sure that nothing is sent before the script is processed.
2. Loading the whole DOM in a Javascript variable then echoing it out after all is loaded.

Which do you reckon is the best way that will work on all browsers and even on the slow computers? I haven't tested it on a variety of platforms and computers with varying speeds and RAM. If you have experience with media heavy sites or have a better way, please let me know which path to take.

Comment: Do not sit on the chair of a browser maker. Keep everything as small as possible, the browser will load most stuff asynchrounus

Comment: The only solution is to hide your entire page until after `window.onload`, however that may result in users leaving your site due to how long they have to wait to get to your content. The better way to fix this would be to reduce the impact of images on your page load by optimizing images, replacing images with css styles, combining images in image sprites where necessary, etc.

Comment: Why would you want this? May the UX god come and beat you up.

Comment: Try to put your huge JS (if there are some) just before `</body>`

Comment: Consider combining images into sprites. That would improve performance significantly. How many image HTTP request are made? Are all images on the same domain?

Comment: Lol...I'm doing this because when the page is loading on those computers i've mentioned, it looks like a human being being formed from the skeleton to the meat slowly.

Comment: @WilliamTheDev Another thing, define image dimensions on the image elements. That way your page contents won't shift during page load.

Comment: Sime...like `<img height='' width=''` ?

Comment: Can you just post a link to this site? There are dozens of best practices that help with load speed and rendering, but without seeing your code it's hard to imagine what suggestions to make (other than using a CDN)

Comment: the images are loaded via separate http requests generally, and unless they're being served up by php scripts, any buffering you do in the main html-building php script is NOT going to change the fact that the images are downloaded separately. in fact, until the client browser gets hold of your html, it can't even start downloading the pictures, unless you embed them as data uris, which bogs down the slow links even more.

Comment: @Ben D http://jayctech.com ...i'm not a front-end guy, i'm back-end. The guy who does the front-end stuff is away for a while and i'm trying to do this stuff by myself.

Comment: Analyze the page vie http://gtmetrix.com/

Comment: _"I have this website that is heavy in images and text"_... ~ Text is nothing, focus on your images.  Make the image file sizes as small as possible using image processing software like PhotoShop.  Usually the images, by far, are the largest things on the page.  Without seeing your page, and if you say it's heavy in images then this is the most obvious thing to point at.

Comment: It came up quick enough in my browser but I put it through gtmetrix.com and it gives you an "F" in four categories... three are for images.

Comment: Yeah...that's why I was asking on the course to take to ensure good UX for even the slow browsers. I'll follow those Gtmetrix.com recommendations.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you can afford to rely on JavaScrip, there is a simple and effective solution **to show all the content at once**.

1. Put a white layer on top of the whole window. This hides all the content.
2. Use event `window.onload` to hide/remove the covering layer.
3. Use event `window.onunload` to show up again the hiding layer.

The layer:

```
    ...
    <style>
        html, body{ height: 100%; }
        #hiding {
            display:    block;
            width:      100%;
            height:     100%;
            position:   absolute;
            top:        0;
            left:       0;
            background: #fff;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="hiding"></div>
    ...
```

JavaScript events:

```
        ...
        <script>
            window.onload = function () {
                document.getElementById('hiding').style.display = 'none';
            };
            window.onunload = function () {
                document.getElementById('hiding').style.display = 'block';
            };
        </scritp>
    </body>
</html>
```

**NOTE:** Do NOT put those styles nor JavaScript code into external files.

**NOTE 2:** It would be nice to place a loading spinner in the middle of the hiding layer. You can add this to `#hiding { ... }` style block: `background: #fff url(/images/spinner.gif) center center;`

Answer (score 2):

1. Host your images in CDN
2. Use image or page caching like timthumb
3. Preload your images using javascript or jquery
4. Use div or section rather than tables for layouts. ( I remember those old school website and how they load )
5. Use a progressive image format
6. GZIP Compression

Comment: +1 for hosting images on a CDN (or otherwise splitting the requests across multiple hosts)

Comment: He said `Lol...I'm doing this because when the page is loading on those computers i've mentioned, it looks like a human being being formed from the skeleton to the meat slowly`

Comment: All those rules are good but that does not display everything at once.

Answer (score 2):

When the browser requests a HTML document, it fires an HTTP call. Then it starts examining the page content, and when it finds external resources (css files, scripts, images) it makes **other HTTP requests asynchronously** (usually not more than 2 to the same server), and when the resource is successfully retrieved (or even before, if it's a CSS for example), it starts examining it.

So there's nothing on the PHP side you can do (buffering the output? Why do you think it should work?)

If your application needs to load resources before starting (eg it's like a game with a loading screen) you have to manage it yourself. For example your main HTML document will contain only a JS file, which in turn will download the resources. When all of the resources (images in this case, plus some text files) have been loaded, the script will *build* the page (again, you may find some tricks to recycle existing technologies like DOM, but that's definitely up to you).

To speed up the retrieval of images, you can use high-speed servers (CDN), or (even better if appropriate), you can combine **all of your images** into a single big one, and split it on the client side. This is often use in case your app is truly a game.

Comment: +1 for sprites... between a CDN and using sprites it will dramatically reduce the staggered-loading. The sprites will ensure that all images display at the same time, and the CDN will allow the client to download multiple dependent files simultaneously...

Answer (score 2):

When the php ends, it output the HTML code and, within, images source path (and css, js, etc files too).. Then, the browser will begin new requests to get that external content required by the page..

If you are trying to print everething at once (once images and other resources are fully loaded) then you could do this with css and js..

With css, you could hide the "main wrapper" of the page, with display: none rule.. If you wish, you could have a "loading" text or gif based image to show the end user that the page is currently loading..

Then, in javascript implement window.onload callback (not jquery ready event). Window.onload event will trigger once the dom is ready and all the resources are fully loaded. [You can see this explained in second paragraph](http://dean.edwards.name/weblog/2005/09/busted/)

Then, in that onload callback, you just have to display: block the hidden "main wrapper" content, and remove or hide the "loading" message.