# Display progress bar until page load in php?

Tags: php, javascript, html

I have an HTML form for which the target is a PHP file.  After clicking submit button, it takes some time to load my PHP file [because I am running some background process], So I want to display a progress bar box [or alert] until the PHP file is loaded.

Can anyone suggest to me how I can accomplish this?

Comment: I shouldn't waste time to add a progressbar because: 1 PHP file won't take so much time (I hope). 2 It will delay your application. 3 A [loading .gif](http://preloaders.net/) is mostly good enough.

Comment: Look at my answer on [Make sure that the browser displays everything at once](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13072013/make-sure-that-the-browser-displays-everything-at-once/13072997#13072997). You can use that technique in order to display a loading GIF while your applications is *thinking*.

Comment: Personally I would just use something like a 'font awesome spinner' which is just a loading gif. Simply use jQuery to replace the 'submit' button with a spinner.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look into using a JavaScript library like [jQuery](http://jquery.com/). I know that [jQuery mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/) has a loading animation that you can use during an AJAX request.

Comment: Clarification - If you don't send any headers in your form's PHP, you can use jQuery and hook the progressChanged event and show an accurate progress bar.

Comment: @Ruirize I didn't know that was possible! Is there some reference somewhere on how to do it?

Comment: See: http://ajaxpatterns.org/HTTP_Streaming
I was mistaken in my statement about `progressChanged` - there is no such thing. Seems like something that should exist really.

Comment: Confused ...Am doing it on Ubuntu machine . Will jQuery work on it ? how can i install jQuery in ubuntu ??

Comment: jQuery is a JavaScript library. I'm assuming you're already using AJAX to do your form submit. You simply include the jQuery file before your JavaScripts to use it: `<script src=http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js></script>`.

Comment: @rink.attendant.6 Am not using AJAX. it is simple form submission.Thnx

Comment: Well if it takes that long for the PHP file to execute that you think a progress bar is suitable, perhaps you should optimize your PHP code or consider using AJAX.

Comment: @rink.attendant.6 Dude how to check the status,the php file is loaded or not ??

Answer (score 0):

These can get tricky.  First, your background task needs to report progress somewhere.  It could be writing to a file, or updating a record in a database.

Next, you'll need a php script that checks the value of the progress.  For example, just pull it out of the database and report the current value.

Finally, you'll need to update your progress bar.  Start with something like this:
http://docs.jquery.com/UI/API/1.8/Progressbar

Just have your javascript perform an ajax request to your progress script and update the value in the progress bar accordingly.

Comment: That's a little convoluted, and I imagine unscalable. (Unless of course this PHP script takes more than a minute or so.)

Comment: Please feel free to offer a better solution.  I've built these for a variety of applications, and scaling is not an issue.  The answer is vague, because the question is also vague.  I'd be happy to provide a greater degree of detail if the OP can give us more to work with.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what sort of traffic were you getting for these applications? This method just seems a little hackish.

Answer (score 0):

Use ajax for the post and use [jQuery BlockUI](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/block/) plugin. When the form is submitted, block the UI. When the script is finished, simply unblock the UI and display the results.